# Equivalent formulations of the Zariski tangent space

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I read alternative definitions of the Zariski tangent space.

Let $k$ be a field.

**Definition 1:** The Zariski tangent space to a $k$-rational point $p$ of an affine variety $X\subset\overline k^n$, is the set of $k$-derivations of the coordinate ring $k[X]$ of $X$ at the point $p$.

**Definition 2:** The Zariski tangent space to a point $p$ of an affine variety $X/k\subset\overline k^n$, defined over $k$, is the set of $k$-derivations of the local ring $O_p(X)$ of $p$.

If $X$ is defined over $k$, each derivation from definition one can be extended by linearity to a derivation of the local ring of $p$, but is this correspondence surjective? Furthermore, if $X$ is an arbitrary variety, how does definition two extend to $k$-rational points of $X$?

Comment: Isn't the coordinate ring at the point $p$ the local ring?

Comment: The local ring at a point is the localization of the coordinate ring by the maximal ideal of the point. @user40276

Comment: Yes, but isn't $k[X]$ at $p$  the localization at $p$? So you mean that in one you use a prime ideal and in the other you use the maximal ideal that contains the prime ideal (the closure).

Comment: The localization of which ring and by which ideal would it be?... I don't think the coordinate ring is a localization. It is a factor of the ring of polynomials by the ideal of the variety.

Comment: Yes, but how you distinguish the coordinate rings at different points by your definition?

Comment: You take the localization by the maximal ideal generated by the point. If $p=(p_1,\dots,p_n)$, then $m_p=\langle x_1-p_1+I(X),\dots,x_n-p_n+I(X) \rangle$ and $O_p(X)$ turns out to be $k[x]_{m_p}$ If you have any more questions, please ask them in a separate post.

Comment: So what's your definition of the coordinate ring at $p$? Are working with the maximal spectrum?

Comment: @Student It doesn't make sense to talk about the coordinate ring of an arbitrary variety – only affine ones.

Comment: @ZhenLin In some russian books, I've ever saw coordinate ring being used as the name for the structure sheaf, though it's weird.

Comment: @ZhenLin It makes perfect sense if you define the coordinate ring in terms of equivalence classes of regular functions. Moreover, the coordinate ring of a variety coincides with the coordinate ring of any of its open subsets.

Comment: @Student That's not the coordinate ring. That's the field of rational functions.

Comment: Pardon me, Mr.\Mrs. @Lin. Whatever I said about the "coordinate ring" in my last comment is true about the "local ring.” Still one can define the coordinate ring of a projective variety as the factor of the polynomial ring by the homogenous ideal of the variety.

Comment: @user40276 Since your comment "Yes, but how you distinguish the coordinate rings at different points by your definition?" I interchanged the terms "coordinate ring" and "local ring." Henceforth, what I said about the "coordinate ring," I meant about the "local ring."

Comment: @user40276 To answer your question, you don't distinguish between the coordinate ring of a variety at different points of the variety, because you only define it for a variety as a whole.

Comment: Ok, but if you don't distinguish, the tangent space is the same at each point.

Comment: That is not true, @user40276. You consider derivations at a point and that's how you distinguish them. But once again, please, take this issue to its own post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I defined the tangent space in my question only works for affine varieties $X/k$ defined over the non-algebraically closed field $k$. For the general variety $X$ one defines the tangent space at a point $p$ as the dual to the factor $ m_p(X)/m_p(X)^2$ of the maximal ideal $m_p(X)$ of $p$ in $X$ by its square $m_p(X)^2$

The two definitions from the question are equivalent when $X/k$ is defined over $k$ and $p$ is a $k$-rational point of $X$, in the sense that the spaces are isomorphic. However, the correspondence I suggested does not extend by linearity. Rather it may extend by continuity, given suitable topologies. Note  here a purely algebraic construction of an isomorphism. Any extension of derivations at a point $p$, needs to preserve the Leibniz rule such that if $f=\frac{f_1}{f_2}\in O_p(X)$ then

$$\overline D_p(f_1) = \overline D_p(f_2f) = \overline D_p(f_2)f(p) + f_2(p)\overline D_p(f)$$

This gives an explicit formula for the continuation $\overline D_p:O_p(X)\to k$ of $D_p:k[X]\to k$, namely

$$\overline D_p(\frac{f_1}{f_2})=\frac{D_p(f_1)f_2(p) - f_1(p)D_p(f_2)}{f_2(p)^2}$$

Easily one can see that this is an injective homomorphism and its inverse is the restriction of derivations to the coordinate ring.